# Invalid ThreadStackSize value - Apache error

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, wamp

I receive this errors below in my Apache server when it receives a large number of visits:

> [Sun Aug 10 00:27:52.496342 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7340:tid 284] AH00428: Parent: child process 10028 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
>
> AH00526: Syntax error on line 110 of C:/apache/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf:
>
> **Invalid ThreadStackSize value: 8388608**

httpd-mpm.conf:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild         1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
    ThreadStackSize         8388608
</IfModule>
```

**Apache 2.4.6 win64 VC11 update3**

After the error the server simply closes. Already googled about this error I have not found absolutely nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've set unrealistic values for `ThreadStackSize` in combination with `ThreadsPerChild`, in the httpd-mpm.conf file.

You've told Apache to start with 1000 threads, each having an 8MB stack size. That's an 8GB Apache process!

You should set `ThreadPerChild` to a reasonable value such as 128, and comment out `ThreadStackSize` so the default value is used, or set it to 2-4MB.

**Edit:** Reading the Apache 2.4.7 changelog I've found this:

```
Fix: Potential rejection of valid MaxMemFree and ThreadStackSize directives
```

This could also be at play here since you are using Apache 2.4.6.